# Variable assignment not happening

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I am having a problem like this;

```
  root@B056HAP2865372:~# str="$(consul-template --version)"
  consul-template v0.18.1 (9c62737)
  root@B056HAP2865372:~# echo $str

  root@B056HAP2865372:~# consul-template --version | cut -d" " -f 2
  consul-template v0.18.1 (9c62737)
```

so the command `$consul-template --version` works, but I cant assign it to any variable or **pipe** it to some other command.

If it helps this machine is a `LXC 2.9.3` container.
It's a bash shell.
I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command is writing it on `stderr`. You can redirect stderr to stdout and then assign to a variable:

```
str="$(consul-template --version 2>&1)"
```